# in r, any recommendations for assigning labels to values in a variable without dummy coding?

Tags: r

I have a variable that has two values. Say 0 = Failed, 1 = Passed.

I would like to keep the variable name but change its values to failed and passed. I have tried using factor_recode and add_labels using the xpss library though for some reason they change the variable values to NA.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course, you can do `var <- factor(var, levels = 0:1, labels = c("Failed", "Passed"))`

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834383/10366237).